intermittent 'Failed to get error from response' from LWC's calling an Apex Class
I have a public Experience Cloud site, comprising various LWCs calling imported Apex classes. I am very occasionally seeing error messages of the type 'Failed to get error from response', but don't know why. The code works 99% of the time, when I see the error, its often in pairs with the same time stamp. This makes me wonder whether it's to do with people double clicking on a link to the landing page in question?
I think I am following standard practice in calling the Apex from the LWC JS, but then what's causing the problem and what's the correct work around? I cant find anything relevant on the Salesforce known issue portal.
LWC JS:
import getList from '@salesforce/apex/cbpCommunityVolunteer.getList';
...
    async getList(region, contactId){
        try{
            if(!this.loading){
                if(this.getListReq!=this.getListResp) sendMessageToAdmin('Parallel calls to cbpCommunityVolunteerRegister '+this.getContactReq+'/'+this.getContactResp);
                this.loading=true;
                this.list = await getList({region:region, contactId:contactId});   
                this.loading=false;
            }
        }catch(error){
            this.loading=false;
            this.displayError('getList - '+this.getContactReq+'/'+this.getContactResp, error);
        }
    }

Apex:
@AuraEnabled
public static List<cbpBookSort> getList(String region, Id contactId){
    try {
        Contact c = cbpContact.getContact(contactId);
        Date d = System.today();

        if(System.now().hour()>=10) d = d.addDays(1);
        List<cbpBookSort> results = new List<cbpBookSort>();
        ...
        return results;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw cbpEmail.newAuraHandledException(e);
    }
}

Where cbpEmail.newAuraHandledException(e), is based on the answer to this similar question, superseding a direct 'throw new AuraHandledException(...)' approach, that  the displayed the same intermittent problem:
public static AuraHandledException newAuraHandledException(Exception e){
    try{
        String m = 'Darn: '+e.getMessage()+' Trace: '+e.getStackTraceString();
        AuraHandledException ahe = new AuraHandledException(m);
        ahe.setMessage(m);
        return ahe;
    }catch(Exception e2){
        sendMessageToAdmin('cbpEmail.newAuraHandledException2: '+e2.getMessage());
        return new AuraHandledException('Unknown error - error generating error message!');
    }
}

